# Adjusting window-size to surf()-plot, Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

We're encountering a problem while plotting the frequency of our signal with the `surf()`-function. As you can see in the picture below, it doesn't fully fill up the plot window. How do we adjust it so that the left plot fills out the graph as well as the right one (which is using `spectrogram()`)?

Picture of our plots:

[image: Snapshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `xlim` and `ylim` to set the limits of the x and y axes. In your case, you could consider something like:

```
ylim([min(Frequency) max(Frequency)]
```

Comment: Okay, thank you! Should we write that on a separate line before or after the surf()-line, or integrate it somehow.. ? :-)

Comment: We got it to work by using it on the line below our surf()-line, thank you so much!

Comment: @zacdawg: [Accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) the answer if it works for you.